# Change jest test output (iTerm being weird)

Tags: jestjs, iterm2, iterm

I am using latest iTerm on catalina with the "Semantic History" feature which allows you to Cmd+Click urls and filename/paths in the terminal. I set iTerm to open vscode:
[image: screenshot of iterm settings Profiles>Advanced>Semantic History]

This seems to work well if the text is like "src/foo/bar.js:3:3" - however if the text is like "src/foo/bar.js" it treats it like a file url. When you hold CMD and hover over these pure file paths, it shows the full file url in the bottom right, just like when you hover over links inside a browser:

[image: screenshot of iterm cmd+hovering over link]

What ends up happening with the `file://` url is it will open the default app specified by the OS. On one hand, iterm should be smart enough to know that we want to open files in our editor... On the other hand, it would be nice if Jest also added the column and line number for iterm to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, clicking the last stack frame at bottom of the stack trace goes directly to the highlighted error line+column number.